# query group name but display other rows with limit

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

### Table

```
+----+-----+------------+
|col1|col2 |col3        |
+----+-----+------------+
|A   |one  |1-jul-2013  |
|A   |two  |2-jul-2013  |
|A   |three|3-jul-2013  |
|A   |four |4-jul-2013  |
|A   |five |5-jul-2013  |
|B   |one  |1-jul-2013  |
|B   |two  |2-jul-2013  |
|B   |three|3-jul-2013  |
|B   |four |4-jul-2013  |
|B   |five |5-jul-2013  |
|B   |six  |6-jul-2013  |
|B   |seven|7-jul-2013  |
|B   |eight|8-jul-2013  |
|C   |one  |1-jul-2013  |
|C   |two  |2-jul-2013  |
|C   |three|3-jul-2013  |
|C   |four |4-jul-2013  |
|C   |five |5-jul-2013  |
|D   |one  |1-jul-2013  |
|D   |two  |2-jul-2013  |
|D   |three|3-jul-2013  |
|D   |four |4-jul-2013  |
|D   |five |5-jul-2013  |
+----+-----+------------+
```

I would like the display to look like this:

```
+-----+------+------------+------------+------------+
|Group|Name  |Date        |Name        |Date        |        
+-----+------+------------+------------+------------+
| A   |one   |1-jul-2013  |two         |2-jul-2013  |
| B   |one   |1-jul-2013  |two         |2-jul-2013  |
| C   |one   |1-jul-2013  |two         |2-jul-2013  |
| D   |one   |1-jul-2013  |two         |2-jul-2013  |
+-----+------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want that?
Having the same column names next to each other makes it a bit hard to figure out which one you need.
As far as I know, it's not possible to have duplicate column names.

Comment: This can't be an answer. This should be a comment.

Comment: its for reporting don't focus on ( Group|Name  |Date      |Name        |Date      ) its just supposed name and its for our database reporting GROUP is our client ID and name is our ORDERs which we update daily basis so 8 month's  3000 orders from 400 client id .. we need all client ID in Group Mean Remove Duplicates just show one ID and the next 4 column show only 2 latest orders from each customer ID with date

Comment: its possible with group coding ( SEE THIS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455515/mysql-query-select-distinct-but-display-all-rows) but its show all record not latest 2 records

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that what you want is all records together for a value of col1, rather than specific columns returned for each value.

If so using GROUP_CONCAT:-

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('-', col2, col3) SEPARATOR ':')
FROM some_table
GROUP BY col1
```

If you want that to be a bit more easily processed and your data is fairly simple you can build up the returned concatenated column as a JSON encoded array (and so can just use JSON_DECODE to turn it into an array to process in PHP):-

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, CONCAT('{\"', CONCAT('{\\\"', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('\\\":\\\"', col2, col3) SEPARATOR '\\\",\\\"') ,'\\\"}')
FROM some_table
GROUP BY col1";
```

If you actually wanted something in the format you have there (and ignoring multiple columns with the same name) then you can use and IF to check a columns value to decide whether to return another columns value, and an aggregate function to just force one value to be returned for that column:-

```
SELECT col1, 
        'one',
        MAX(IF(col2='one', col3, NULL)),
        'two',
        MAX(IF(col2='two', col3, NULL)),
        'three',
        MAX(IF(col2='three', col3, NULL)),
        'four',
        MAX(IF(col2='four', col3, NULL)),
        'five',
        MAX(IF(col2='five', col3, NULL)),
        'six',
        MAX(IF(col2='six', col3, NULL)),
        'seven',
        MAX(IF(col2='seven', col3, NULL)),
        'eight',
        MAX(IF(col2='eight', col3, NULL))
FROM some_table
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT work fine but its also show all record can we show GROUP_CONCAT Limited value

Comment: Yes, you can just add a WHERE clause. For example _WHERE col2 IN ('one', 'two')_

Comment: i need limit in numbers mean LIMIT 2 type some thing

Comment: There is no option for that on GROUP_CONCAT, but you could use SUBSTRING_INDEX on the results of it. For example _SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('-', col2, col3) SEPARATOR ':'), ':', 2)_